# my css doesnt run in a json generated div

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, json

I am trying to fill a div with data using json.
But my div, set with javascript for each json element, doesn't run.
The classes lulu and lora don't run.
Sorry my bad English, I hope it was clear.

Can someone help me?
Thanks.

Here my code:

**JS:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function() {
    var url="animals.json";

    $.getJSON(url, function(json) {
      $.each(json.cats, function(i,item) {
        $('<div class="lulu">' + 
          '<img src="pics/style/blank.gif" data-src="img/'+item.pictures+'.jpg"/>' +
          '<img class="lora" src="img/'+item.picsmall+'.jpg"/>'+'</div>')
          .appendTo('#Mittelt');
      });
    });
  });
</script>
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="rosa" id="Mittelt">
  // place to append
</div>
```

**JSON:**

```
{"cats":[
         {"id":"1",
          "pictures":"mia",
          "picsmall":"miasmall"}
         ]
}
```

**CSS**

```
.lulu {
    position:absolute;
    height:100%;
    -webkit-transform: translateZ(0px);
    -ms-transform: translateZ(0px);
    -o-transform: translateZ(0px);
    transform: translateZ(0px);
}
```

The json runs perfect, the result is as if there is no class.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Cannot reproduce (no console errors and class is applied) -> https://jsfiddle.net/azizn/6axmhko6/

Comment: Can you give the json format? `item.pictures` indicates an array..

Comment: @user3690260 Code looks fine. Looks like maybe your css class `lora` is not being applied. What's the css rule?

Comment: @Candide updatet with the css rule. but lulu doesnt applied too. and i have no idea why.

Comment: @Candide its possible to add the classes after the div is loaded?

Comment: @user3690260 Also cannot reproduce, please check here: http://multiverso.ddns.net:8012/stackoverflow/1/test.html

Are you trying to run it on a local file system (file://) instead of a web server?

Comment: @Sagito i tried it on a webserver. but i think a solution could be, when i add the css to a div, after the json append it. or creat the div, and then put it on every item.

Comment: Your `.lulu` class has `position: absolute` and will need a width as well, like `width: 200px;` or else it will collapse to 0 ... have you tried that?

Comment: just tried, but no solution :-(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JSON format of animals.json is little wrong.

Include below

```
var json=url["cats"];  
 $(json).each(function(item){  
    console.log(json[0].id);  
   item=json[0];
```

codepen-http://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/gMwXaK

Comment: for testing, i have used few dummy images which you can replace with actual images ...Hope this works for you :)

Comment: I have added another cats object to animals with id 2 and it works fine

Comment: yes ..to make image to change ..i have .lulu img {height:50%}

Comment: Two codepens with two logics 
http://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/gMwXaK    works with same json with one object and height of images can be controlled 
 
codepen.io/nagasai/pen/PzGOpy    works with multiple cats object and height control also works

Comment: You are my hero =) no it does show right. but where was my problem?
And when i make in my json a oter id with a picturename, than it show only the first id picture two time. not 2 diffrent pictures! Any idea?

Comment: form complete URL before assigning it to the HTML
'<img src="' + item.pictures + '"/>' +
        '<img class="lora" src="' + item.picsmall + '"/>'

Make sure that the complete URL is built for item.pictures= 'img/mia.jpg'

Comment: and try giving absolute path once and test ..and if it is displaying twice , then in the loop , same values are passed i mean only first value is getting passed...check loop..console log loop value...Hope that helps you :)

Comment: Do you have an idea how to chance the code? it must be something with each.
https://jsfiddle.net/5wyL5azj/

Comment: For runnung loop , we should use index i and run loop , json[0] will always point to first one and you were using same imagesfor pictures and picsmall and remove position absolute to avoid images getting overlapped ....Updated fiddle with comments-https://jsfiddle.net/Nagasai_Aytha/5wyL5azj/13/